# How to target "Main" script and not "Module" script in Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm running into a build issue on a large project, which I can reproduce in an extremely simplistic example:

Given a basic webpack project (from Getting Started):

```
[webpack]: ls
node_modules            package.json
package-lock.json       src

[webpack]: ls src
index.js
```

If I try to import a package that has a "module" listed in package.json (which I **cannot** find a reference for in https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json), like **@szhsin/react-menu** (https://github.com/szhsin/react-menu/blob/master/package.json#L9-L10), then Webpack tries to import that, instead of the "main" script!

### Example

```js
// src/index.js
import '@szhsin/react-menu'
```

```
[webpack]: npx webpack
[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
assets by status 33.4 KiB [cached] 1 asset
orphan modules 42.2 KiB [orphan] 1 module
./src/index.js + 1 modules 42.2 KiB [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@szhsin/react-menu/dist/index.modern.js 1:0-122
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in '/Users/delong/dev/webpack/node_modules/@szhsin/react-menu/dist'
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-27
```

Note: It's trying to import `dist/index.modern.js`, and not `dist/index.js`!

How do I need to configure Webpack in order to default to importing the "main" script?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the full path:

```
import '@szhsin/react-menu/dist/index.js'
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution.  Simple, explicit.  Now I'm left curious as to what the downsides are (other than typing out more characters).

Comment: It will break your build once they change the path of `dist/index.js`.